# Search directly Google Dictionary

Tags: google-search, google-dictionary

Google Dictionary was great tool. Google shut it down. Is there any way I can directly search Google Dictionary, like for this [definition of "phew"](http://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ix=sea&ie=UTF-8&ion=1&nord=1#hl=en&safe=off&nord=1&qscrl=1&site=webhp&q=phew&tbs=dfn:1&tbo=u&sa=X&ei=wlwET-OSEdD74QTS-MmTCA&ved=0CDIQkQ4&fp=1&ion=1&biw=1024&bih=621&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&cad=b)?

Comment: This is not perfect but here is a workaround: http://www.google.com/insidesearch/features.html#dictionary

Answer (score 2):

You can use the keyword/term `define` before the term to be defined. So your Google query will be `define phew`.

Also, if you're using Google Chrome, you can install [Google Dictionary extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mgijmajocgfcbeboacabfgobmjgjcoja). In Firefox, a similar extension is called [Wiktionary and Google Translate](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/google-dictionary-and-google-t/).